# Is it possible to keep data cached between user visits

Tags: meteor

I have a collection of 15k+ objects(database) that I want to send to the client(an application). This can take up to 30sec to sync.

I would like a way to keep cache between user visits so I only need to sync the difference since my last visit.

It would be also nice to be able to share that local cache between browser tabs.

In theory I don't see why it would be hard to do so, but I am uncertain how to do it.

*As pointed out by @zeroasterisk it is a database cache I am looking for, not simply static files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the smart package "appcache" ?

- code: https://github.com/awwx/meteor-appcache
- info: http://docs.meteor.com/#appcache
- more: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/AppCache

The appcache package stores the static parts of a Meteor application (the client side Javascript, HTML, CSS, and images) in the browser's application cache. To enable caching simply add the appcache package to your project.

It doesn't currently support data in collections, which is what I think you were asking about, but it might be something you could extend.  If I mis-understood the question and you just need to store static objects (JS files, etc) this will work great.

more on this here: [Can Meteor's Appcache also store database data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478597/can-meteors-appcache-also-store-database-data)

note: it is disabled by default in FF because of user prompts...

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I know about appcache and it's great, but you are right in assuming that it is what I actually want to cache. I'll update the question to be more evident.